# Using View with data.frame subset adds row.names column

Tags: r, dataframe

I create two subsets (data.frames) like so:

```
sms_raw_train <- sms_raw[1:4169, ]
sms_raw_test <- sms_raw[4170:5559, ]
```

The first, `sms_raw_train`, looks like this:

```
    type    text
1   ham Hope you are having a good week. Just checking in
2   ham K..give back my thanks.
3   ham Am also doing in cbe only. But have to pay.
```

The second, `sms_raw_test`, looks like this:

```
    row.names   type    text
1   4170    ham I'm coming home 4 dinner.
2   4171    ham Come by our room at some point so we can iron out the plan for this weekend
3   4172    ham Its sunny in california. The weather's just cool
```

As you can see, it adds a `row.names` column.  However, if I do this:

```
> str(sms_raw_test[1:3, ])
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ type: Factor w/ 2 levels "ham","spam": 1 1 1
 $ text: chr  "I'm coming home 4 dinner." "Come by our room at some point so we can iron out the plan for this weekend" "Its sunny in california. The weather's just cool"
```

The column doesn't actually exist.

What is the purpose of this column?  Why was it added to the `View(sms_raw_train)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`View` is adding that column for display.  As you have seen, it is not actually present in the subset.

From `help(View)`:

```
If there are row names on the data frame that are not 1:nrow, they are displayed in a separate first column called row.names.
```

The row names for `sms_raw_data` are (presumably) `4170:5559`.

The row names for `sms_raw_train` are `1:nrow` so this behavior is not evident there.

Comment: Thanks but I don't quite understand your answer.  The two dataframes should be identical, so why would the training data not show this column but the test data does?

Comment: @user1477388 They are not different. They are only **displayed** differently if you use `View`.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying since I didn't start from row 1 the View() method will add the column to indicate the row from which I started.  That make sense and it quite helpful.  Thanks.